# XElement => Add children nodes at run time

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

So let's assume this is what i want to achieve:

```
<root>
  <name>AAAA</name>
  <last>BBBB</last>
  <children>
     <child>
        <name>XXX</name>
        <last>TTT</last>
     </child>
     <child>
        <name>OOO</name>
        <last>PPP</last>
     </child>
   </children>
</root>
```

**Not sure if using XElement is the simplest way**
but this is what I have so far:

```
 XElement x = new XElement("root",
                  new XElement("name", "AAA"),
                  new XElement("last", "BBB"));
```

Now I have to add the "children" based on some data i have.
There could be 1,2,3,4 ...

so I need to iterate thru my list to get every single child

```
foreach (Children c in family)
{
    x.Add(new XElement("child", 
              new XElement("name", "XXX"),
              new XElement("last", "TTT")); 
}
```

## **PROBLEM:**

Doing this way I will be missing the "CHILDREN Parent node".
If I just add it before the foreach, it will be rendered as a closed node

```
<children/>
```

and that's NOT what we want.

## **QUESTION:**

How can I add to the 1st part a parent node  and as many  as my list has?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = new XElement("root",
             new XElement("name", "AAA"),
             new XElement("last", "BBB"),
             new XElement("children",
                 from c in family
                 select new XElement("child",
                             new XElement("name", "XXX"),
                             new XElement("last", "TTT")
                        )
             )
        );
```

Answer (score 34):

```
 XElement root = new XElement("root",
                  new XElement("name", "AAA"),
                  new XElement("last", "BBB"));

XElement children = new XElement("children");

foreach (Children c in family)
{
    children.Add(new XElement("child", 
              new XElement("name", c.Name),
              new XElement("last", c.Last)); 
}
root.Add(children);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var children = new XElement("children");
XElement x = new XElement("root",
                  new XElement("name", "AAA"),
                  new XElement("last", "BBB"),
                  children);

foreach (Children c in family)
{
    children.Add(new XElement("child", 
              new XElement("name", "XXX"),
              new XElement("last", "TTT")); 
}
```