# How to insert a child element into an existing element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am using a XDocument to write an xml file and I am writing to the document in two different places.  After the first write I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<suspensedata connectionid="000" customerid="000" name="MyName" />
```

After the second write I want the file to look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<suspensedata connectionid="560" customerid="131" name="ImgTransfer2327">
  <transaction DocumentID="46" SuspenseID="7">
    <field id="LocationID">000000015000</field>
    <field id="AccountNumber">50000</field>
    <field id="AmountPaid">25.00</field>
    <field id="CheckAmount">100.00</field>
    <field id="CheckNo">000</field>
  </transaction>
</suspensedata>
```

But I can't seem to get the insert done correctly.

I've tried (The name of my `XDocument` is ValidXml) `ValidXml.Root.Add(new Element("transaction"));`
and that does not change anything.

I have also tried `ValidXml.Element("suspensedata").Add(new XElement("transaction"));`
But that did not work either.

How would I add this child element?

EDIT: Both attempts did not produce any other output besides the output on the first try.  Also I did make sure to use ValidXml.Save()

Comment: this might be the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558763/xelement-add-children-nodes-at-run-time

Comment: What did you get?  Did it produce no input or invalid input?

Comment: @Vulcronos IT produced no new output.  I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried something like this  I supposed that the two parts are in 2 files

//xmlfile1 contains the first part

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <suspensedata connectionid="000" customerid="000" name="MyName" />
```

//this part will be loaded  like this

```
  XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("xmlfile1.xml");
       XElement elt = xDoc.Root;
```

//and the second file contains the second part

```
         XDocument xDoc2 = XDocument.Load("xmlfile2.xml");
         XElement elt2 = xDoc2.Root;
         elt.Add(elt2);
         xDoc.Save("xmlfile1.xml");
```

Hope this help